# Вопрос по массивам и выделению памяти

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

Привет всем!

**Вопрос 1:** Есть в методе такая строка:

```
const char *c = "123";
```

Как это присванивание работает? В стеке создается массив с '1','2','3', а затем указатель на массив копируется в "с"? Все верно, ничего не упустил?

**Вопрос 2:** Почему в следующем примере последние элементы заполняются нулями:

```
int b[5] = {7,-4,5};
```

Если массив объявлен как локальный\глобальный, то элементы [3] и [4] содержат нули. Почему? Ведь локальные переменные не должны инициализироваться нулями автоматически.

Comment: Строки создаются не на стеке, а в секции неизменяемых данных, загружаемой в оперативную память при запуске программы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. В сегменте данных создается массив `char` с элементами `'1','2','3',0` и указатель на него присваивается переменной `c`. Причем этот сегмент вполне может быть доступен только для чтения, так что изменить данные в нем будет невозможно.
2. Если есть хоть какая-то инициализация, то недостающие элементы также инициализируются - значением по умолчанию 0.

В C, например, проходит такое -

```
int array[] = { [0] = 2, [100] = -1 };
```

Будет массив из двойки, 99 нулей и 101-й элемент - `-1` :)